# Eloquent query: Filtering results based on relationship with other model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have two tables: `posts` and `categories`. It is a many-to-many relationship: A post has many categories and a category belongs to many posts.
Here are the models that describe their relationships:

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

I want to get all `posts` that have a particular `category`: `tips`

Here is what I tried:

```
$tips = Category::where('name', 'Tips')->posts()->with('categories')->take(4)->get();
```

I don't know the level of ignorance in this query, but I honestly expected it to work. It didn't.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's really as simple as:

```
$tipsCategory = Category::where('name', 'tips')
    ->get();

$posts = $tipsCategory->posts;
```